# Detect REST call originating from outside Cloud Foundry

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, cloud-foundry

I have a Microservices based architecture where Microservices are running in Cloud Foundry and expose REST interfaces. These REST interfaces are invoked by browsers.

I have a requirement that REST calls originating from browsers should be authenticated while requests made from one Microservice to another need not be authenticated.

Since I'm using **OAuth2**, the REST calls originating from browsers would carry JWT and the microservice is expected to verify this JWT. However, requests originating from microservices will not carry JWT and the peer microservice is expected to detect that the request is originating from within Cloud Foundry and hence allow it to pass through. We are using Spring Security filters.

How can a microservice detect if the request is originating from outside Cloud Foundry?

Comment: Since you're using OAuth2, you might want to look at using a client_credentials grant for communication from service to service.  https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified#others